# Python: does my function require return statement?

Tags: python, function, return

I am working on Python function that takes a pandas data file, do some processing on it (sorting, filtering columns and finally saves the output as *.csv file)

```
def apply_filer(df):
       """
       filter data file according to the information in all columns
        """
       df_filter = df[(df['LogP'] < 5) & (df['HBA'] < 10) & (df['HBD'] < 5) & (df['MolWt'] < 500)]
       # sort the lines according to the first column
       df_sorted = df_filter.sort_values('LIGAND', key=lambda x: x.str.split('_').str[1].astype(int))
       # save filtered DF as CSV
       df_sorted.to_csv(results+r'/CNE_lipinski.txt', index=None, sep=' ', mode='a', float_format='%.3f')
       # return processed data files:
       return df_filter, df_sorted
    
pwd = os.getcwd()
results='results'
#set directory with outputs
results = os.path.join(pwd,results) 
#apply the function on pandas data file
apply_filer(df)
```

While it works correctly, producing correct .CSV, do I need to return df_filter, df_sorted in this case ? I have tried to access the both variables from my python script to check the processed datafilles directly in pandas format but it did not work. Also note that result variable (the path to save the CSV file, was defined outside the function and I don't know whether it was correct.

```
>>> df_sorted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'df_sorted' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*df_filter* and *df_sorted* are local variables to the function, the scope of these two are within the function. Where as the path to CSV file is a global variable and its scope will be applicable to all the functions declared in this python script. I cannot say its right/wrong to declare **results** variable outside as it is based on your use case. On personal note, i always felt that if the code is working as expected, then consider it RIGHT.

To answer your question, **do I need to return df_filter, df_sorted in this case ?**. It completely depends on your use case.
As per your code, the return statement **has no effect** as you are not saving those returned values to any variables.

if you want to use these two values outside the function then you got to call your function in below syntax. This way the returned values will be assigned to filter and sorted variables.

```
filter,sorted = apply_filer(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the returned values to variables:

```
def apply_filer(df):
       ...
       # return processed data files:
       return df_filter, df_sorted

# result is tuple (<value_of_df_filter>, <value_of_df_sorted>)
result = apply_filer(df)

# you can unpack the tuple directly into 2 variables
_filtered, _sorted = apply_filer(df)
```